# Locate instances of MS-Word that have no open documents using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel process that would be more efficient if I could determine whether the user has any instances of MS-Word that have no open documents (e.g., because the user has closed all documents but not exited MS-Word).

I tried code found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/268498/collecting-all-instances-of-an-office-application-excel-powerpoint-word) to locate all instances of MS-Word. My plan was to loop through the instances and find any with 0 open documents. That code appears to locate all instances of MS-Word that have >0 open documents, but not instances with 0 open documents.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can not get the "first" Instance with GetObject and check if this instance is visible and has Documents open?
This will have probs, if the user has more than one instance of word open (but this should be a problem itself)

Comment: See https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2019/01/vba-code-to-get-excel-word-powerpoint.html#Word - the code you reference seems to focus on finding the *document* window, but if there's no document then maybe it's better to try for some other window in order to get the Application reference.  From the link, maybe the Statusbar would do it?

Comment: Oh, interesting.  It looks like I have to have a document open in order to have a "WwG" window class.  According to the documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-accessibleobjectfromwindow), it looks like AccessibleObjectFromWindow can return a Word application objection only when passed a "WwG" window class.  So I don't think my current approach is going to work.  (Unfortunately, I need support for multiple instances of Word, so GetObject isn't going to cut it here.)

Answer (score 0):

See example below: `WordInstanceMap()` gives you all Word instances with open documents, in a Collection with their process Id's as a key.  You could use WMI to get all open Word instance process id's, and compare those to the ones in the Collection (eg. try adding an item with the process id as a key, and trap the error if the key already exists)

That will give you process id's for word instances with no open docs: at that point it may be better to terminate those and fire up a new instance (that would be the easiest way to get a reference to an empty instance).

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim col As Collection, colAll As Collection, proc
    
    Set colAll = RunningInstanceProcessIds("WINWORD.EXE")
    Debug.Print "All instances count", colAll.Count
    
    'https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/268498/collecting-all-instances-of-an-office-application-excel-powerpoint-word
    Set col = WordInstanceMap() 'from link above
    
    For Each proc In colAll
        If Not CollectionHasKey(col, CStr(proc)) Then
            Debug.Print "Process " & proc & " has no open documents"
        End If
    Next proc
   
End Sub

Function RunningInstanceProcessIds(AppName As String) As Collection
    Dim oWMIService, wProcesses, oPrc
    Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    'return both 32- and 64-bit processes...
    Set wProcesses = oWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process " & _
                                           "WHERE Name = '" & AppName & "'")
    Set RunningInstanceProcessIds = New Collection
    For Each oPrc In wProcesses
        RunningInstanceProcessIds.Add oPrc.ProcessId
    Next
End Function

'Does a keyed collection contain an item with key `k`?
Function CollectionHasKey(col As Collection, k As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo haveErr:
    col.Add "test", k
    col.Remove col.Count     'add succeeded, so remove the item
    CollectionHasKey = False
    Exit Function
haveErr:
    CollectionHasKey = (Err.Number = 457)
End Function
```

I'm not sure that gets you where you want to be though...

Comment: Thanks for thinking through this.  The goal is really to avoid having to open any new instances of Word.  Users run the relevant process 50-100x / day, and by far the slowest part is opening a new instance of Word each time.  I was kind of hoping I could have a hidden instance of Word that always hangs out in the background and gets used each time the process runs.  I suppose I may still be able to get this to work, but I would just need the hidden instance of Word to always have a doc open so that I can find it each time the process runs.  Maybe that's not such a bad thing.

Comment: You can always use GetObject to return any open instance if it doesn’t matter which specific instance you use.